# How to align left reversed v-text-field label

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

reverse property of v-text-field can align right its text.

but i want to keep label left, so i need a way to control label position.

How can i do this?

```
<v-text-field reverse label="number input" append-icon="mdi-magnify" type="number"></v-text-field>
```

[image: reversed v-text-field]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a CSS class to apply to the text-input that targets the label and overrides the positioning.

**.label-left**

```css
.label-left .v-label {
  left: 0 !important;
  transform-origin: top left !important;
}
```

Now you can apply the **label-left** class to the reversed input.

```html
<v-text-field
  class="label-left"
  reverse
  label="number input"
  append-icon="mdi-magnify"
  type="number"
></v-text-field>
```